# How to design a Java fluent DSL API without static methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder, fluent

There are several ways how to define a Java fluent API:

- Use static classes/methods + an internal `ThreadLocal` to get the DSL instance
- Use setter/getter based methods to chain the API. Personally I don't like the readability of it, e.g. see some Spring Security code examples.

Is there a way to create a Java DSL that is more readable, like fluent methods in Kotlin? For exmaple a `Computer` class with Attributes like `cpu`/`gpu` and nested DSL classes like drives (**Note**: I want to nest ssd and hdd even further, e.g. define `partitions`?

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Computer computer = Computer.build("Gaming PC").cpu("AMD 5950X").gpu("Lol rly?");
        computer.drives(() {
            ssd("1TB", "m2");
            hdd("10TB", "SATA");
        });
        computer.print();
    }

    public static class Computer {

        private final Map<String, String> attributes;

        private Computer() {
            this.attributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        }

        public static Computer build(String name) {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.attributes.put("name", name);
            return computer;
        }

        public Computer cpu(String modelName) {
            attributes.put("cpu", modelName);
            return this;
        }

        public Computer gpu(String modelName) {
            attributes.put("gpu", modelName);
            return this;
        }

        // TODO: Add ssd and hdd. How?

        public void print() {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example above won't compile. But is there a way to achieve it with regular classes/abstract classes or even interfaces [with default methods?]. Like this:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Computer computer = Computer.build("Gaming PC").cpu("AMD 5950X").gpu("Lol rly?");
        computer.drives((new DriveManager() {
            ssd("1TB", "m2");
            hdd("10TB", "SATA");
        });
        computer.print();
    }

    public static class DriveManager {

        private Computer computer;

        public void setComputer(Computer computer) {
            this.computer = computer;
        }

        public void ssd(String size, String interfaceType) {
            computer.ssd(size, interfaceType);
        }

        public void hdd(String size, String interfaceType) {
            computer.ssd(size, interfaceType);
        }
    }
}
```

But how does one call `setComputer`?

Comment: Spring Security, e.g. [HttpSecurity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.java), is as fluent and flexible as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection and an anonymous instance can be used.

You only need it for the drives

```
Computer computer = new Computer("Gaming PC") {
    MainboardComponent cpu = new CPU("AMD 5950X");
    MainboardComponent gpu = new GPU("Lol rly?");

    Drive ssd = new SSD("1TB", "m2");
    Drive hdd = new HDD("10TB", "SATA") {
        Partition hdd1 = ...;
        Partition hdd2 = ...;
    };
}
```

This hides those fields however.

This however is useful for things like grammars where you may use inheritance on several levels (protected fields, predefined rules, I/O ports). It has the advantage that the container base class may provide component classes and protected members.

A pure fluent interface is possible too, by letting the ComputerBuilder have a nested DriveBuilder.

```
Computer computer = Computer.build("Gaming PC")
    .cpu("AMD 5950X")
    .gpu("Lol rly?")
    .drives()
        .ssd("1TB", "m2")
        .hdd("10TB", "SATA")
        .endDrives()
    .end();
```

The third alternative would be to use a vararg method `ComputerBuilder drives(DriveBuilder... dds);` (Drive or DriveBuilder).

```
Computer computer = Computer.build("Gaming PC")
    .cpu("AMD 5950X")
    .gpu("Lol rly?")
    .drives(Drive.ssd("1TB", "m2"), Drive.hdd("10TB", "SATA"));
```